# GCP static website returns Error: NoSuchBucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a GCP storage bucket named for a domain managed by Google Domains. I have uploaded the files, created a CNAME record for c.storage.googleapis.com, and changed the ACLs to public-read. However, I'm still getting the error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
  <Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Note that I wasn't asked to verify the domain when I created the bucket. I assume this is normal for a domain managed by Google Domains as it says "automatically verified."

I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it. I just needed to add www. to the beginning of the bucket name.

In other words:
www.domain.com instead of domain.com

Comment: This really helped, in short steps I did: 
Created a bucket www.mysite.com
Edited bucket permissions: (Added new member "allUsers" with role Storage View) 
Edited website configuration of this bucket (Choose index.html)
Done!!!

Comment: I'm quite interested in knowing why this works in that way

Comment: Did you know how to add the confguration records so that it will work even if we hit domain.com

Comment: That’s called a “naked domain.” It depends on which registrar you used how you set it up. You need to add a DNS record (maybe CNAME?). I don’t remember

Comment: Found this for using https https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https

Comment: I made a test website in the format test.example.com and I had to name my bucket the same way. Also, I had to set index.html and my 404.html as the respective pages for the bucket. So the bucket name does not necessarily have to be called www.example.com.